# Is there a better way to write my downsampling function?

Tags: matlab

I have an audio data I read as a csv and to reduce computation I downsample my data before going with further processing.

```
data = csvread( "VoiceTest1.csv");

% downsample data (81:1) to make processing quicker
reducedData = data;
for i = 1:4
  reducedData = reduce(reducedData);
end


function dataReduced = reduce(d)
  x1 = d(1:3:end);  %slice the x0 and x1's
  x2 = d(2:3:end);  %slice the x0 and x1's
  x3 = d(3:3:end);  %slice the x0 and x1's

  smooth = conv([1/2 1/2], [1/2 1/2]);

  s = min([size(x1,1)   size(x2,1)  size(x3,1)]);
  x1 = x1(1:s);
  x2 = x2(1:s);
  x3 = x3(1:s);
  
  dataReduced = x1.*smooth(1) + x2.*smooth(2) + x3.*smooth(3);
end
```

Is there any way to make my function simpler and shorter in matlab rather than creating that function at the end?

Any suggestions?

Comment: For downsamping (with anti-aliasing filer) you can use [`resample`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/resample.html)

Comment: Or just some option of `interp1`

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks! The resample function worked, I ran it in a loop 4 times with p and q as 1 and 3. The decimate function seemed to work too